# How can I return an inorder traversal instead of just printing it

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

As of now, my code only prints out an in-order traveral. However, I would like it to return one.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
def inorder(node):
    if(node==None):
        return
    else:
        inorder(node.left)
        print(node.data)
        inorder(node.right)
root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
```

P.S I know this tree is not a binary search tree.

Comment: Use generators. `yield from` the recursive calls and `yield` the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generators. `yield from` the recursive calls and `yield` the data value.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
def inorder(node):
    if node:
        yield from inorder(node.left)
        yield node.data
        yield from inorder(node.right)
root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)

print(list(inorder(root)))
```

result

> [4, 2, 5, 1, 3]

If you wanted it to use a list and not generators.

```
def inorder_list(node):
    accum = []
    inorder_list_impl(node, accum.append)
    return accum

def inorder_list_impl(node, accumulator):
    if node:
        inorder_list_impl(node.left, accumulator)
        accumulator(node.data)
        inorder_list_impl(node.right, accumulator)
```

You could also use

```
inorder_list_impl(root, print)
```

To just print the values.